# Convert Data to Bool

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata

I have an api call which its response is a data including a bool.
it is **NOT** a JSON object so JSONDecoder fails to decode it. it's some bytes that needs to be converted to a **Bool**.

```
  respose in postman: true or false
```

what is requested :

```
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { responseData, urlResponse, err -> Void in
     let data: Data = responseData
}
```

thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Can you provide format how it is stored in `Data`?

Comment: Please `print(responseData as NSData)` and add the result to the question.

Comment: @vadian printed value is //74727565

Comment: `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)` should work too. Maybe too much efforts just for that, but still.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function should do it:

```
func parse(data: Data) -> Bool? {
    return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8).flatMap(Bool.init)
}
```

Try for yourself:

```
let responseStrings = ["false", "true", "bogus"]
let responseBodies = responseStrings.map { Data($0.utf8) }

responseBodies.map(parse) // => [false, true, nil]
```

Comment: or `responseStrings.map { Data($0.utf8) }` and btw the signature of the method is inferred by the compiler `responseBodies.map(parse)`

Comment: Thanks for `Data($0.utf8)`, didn't know that.

Answer (score 2):

First of all **handle always the `error`**

The response `<74727565>` is a string "true". The easiest solution is to compare `responseData` directly with `Data`

```
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { responseData, _, err  in
    if let error = err { print(error); return }

    let success = responseData! == Data("true".utf8) // or == Data([116,114,117,101])
}
```

`success` is `true` if the response is "true" otherwise `false`.